# how to make dynamic buttons in flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

From this button to
[image]

making a dynamic button like this with ontap.
[image]

i am a biggener in flutter(~2 months)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code:

```
class MyWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyWidgetState createState() => _MyWidgetState();
}

class _MyWidgetState extends State<MyWidget> {
  int i = 0;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Row(children: [
      Visibility(
        visible: i > 0,
        replacement: RaisedButton(
          color: Colors.orangeAccent,
          child: new Text("Add"),
          onPressed: () => setState(() { ++i;}),
        ),
        child: Row(
          children: [
            RaisedButton(
              color: Colors.orangeAccent,
              child: new Text("-"),
              onPressed: () => setState(() { --i;}),
            ),
            Container(
              width: 100,
              child: Text(
                i.toString(),
                textAlign: TextAlign.center,
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
      RaisedButton(
        color: Colors.orangeAccent,
        child: new Text("+"),
        onPressed: () => setState(() { ++i;}),
      )
    ]);
  }
}
```